# Resharper test output is empty in visual studio 'show output from'

Tags: unit-testing, output, resharper, visual-studio-2022, xunit

In Visual Studio 2022, adding some unit test, I could configure the output of each unit test, it's working well as you can see in both images [Red one].

Also, I configured the IMessageSink in a XUnitTestFramework [Blue one], and works well in first image (which it was executed using the ms unit test), but all full output is not showing in second image (which it was executed using Resharper 2023.1 unit test).

Am I missing some configuration in VS to see the test output using Resharper?

[image: MsUnitTest]

[image: ReshaperUnitTest]

Answer (score 0):

R# does show console output for your test (i.e. the result of `Output.WriteLine`). What you're seeing in the Visual Studio window is the output of the Visual Studio test runner. R# uses its own test runner, see [this instruction](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-482066/Support-IMessageSink-in-test-output#focus=Comments-27-7358966.0-0) on how to make R# test runner print the output of `IMessageSink`.